Buying mobile at Chinese airport
Is it possible to buy a smartphone at Chinese airports (Shanghai)? And are prices similar/lower than inside of China?

Which Shanghai airport, Pudong (PVG)? And do you want to buy it airside (before immigration) or landside (after)?

About 10 years ago, I bought a Chinese cell phone+plan as a non-Chinese resident/citizen. It was a tedious and complicated process involving some natives strongly advocating on my behalf with the provider. Given recent developments I would expect it to be even more difficult today. Wee chat may be easier.

Pudong, Terminal 1. Or close to airport if its easy.

I doubt anything sold at an airport is cheaper than in town.  I suggest looking carefully at the detailed specs if you care about esim and physical sim capability. Models officially sold in mainland China (and the US, for that matter) may lack capabilities that models sold in 3rd markets (such as Canada or HK) have.
